Error dumping weights duplicate weight name kernel (tensorflow keras to tensorflowJS export)
I'm having problems to export a simple tensorflow model to a tensorflowjs model, currently I have read the official documentation about recomendations and found the next:
ERROR OUTPUT

failed to lookup keras version from the file,
this is likely a weight only file Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/tensorflowjs_converter", line 8, in

sys.exit(pip_main())
^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py",
line 958, in pip_main
main([' '.join(sys.argv[1:])])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py",
line 962, in main
convert(argv[0].split(' '))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py",
line 948, in convert
_dispatch_converter(input_format, output_format, args, quantization_dtype_map,   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py",
line 618, in _dispatch_converter
dispatch_keras_h5_to_tfjs_layers_model_conversion(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py",
line 98, in dispatch_keras_h5_to_tfjs_layers_model_conversion
conversion.write_artifacts(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/keras_h5_conversion.py",
line 418, in write_artifacts
weights_manifest = write_weights.write_weights(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/write_weights.py",
line 118, in write_weights
_assert_no_duplicate_weight_names(weight_groups)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/write_weights.py",
line 346, in _assert_no_duplicate_weight_names
raise Exception( Exception: Error dumping weights, duplicate weight name kernel

Things to take in account:


I want to use the GPU versión of tensorflow to use full capacity of my graphics card.
My processor has an acceptable power to use the CPU version, but I think if I have a better hardware for this, why not using it?, my CPU it's ok but my graphics card is way better.
According the official documentation of tensorflow, version 2.10 was the latest version of tensorflow that accepts native GPU for Windows by Nvidia, versions higher than 2.10 aren't supported for native Windows Tensorflow pip install.
Tensorflow recommends to use a docker image and deploy a container for GPU, I have initially tried to install CUDA in my Windows system but it failed a bunch of times, so I gave up by using this, so I tried to use the docker image tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter and that's the reason why I'm using docker.
Another reason for me to use the GPU version instead of the CPU version is that my CPU is burning, currently I don't want to stress too much my CPU instead, my GPU is stable.
I literally updated the graphics card drivers a few hours ago, so they are updated (nothing changed).
To changes that affects GPU please restart the kernel in jupyter notebook to take effect.


Useful commands through the operations

If you can't kill the service VmmemWSL.exe and you are getting out of memory you should quit docker desktop and use command in administrator mode:
wsl --shutdown


Note: You can't kill VmmemWSL directly, but you can avoid memory comsuption and memory leak by shutdown wsl , this automatically frees RAM space without killing the unkillable VmmemWSL.exe service.

If you want to check if the Graphics Card is correctly recognized you can use the command inside the container:
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

To run an image with GPU support you can run command (for images that support GPU):
docker run --gpus all -it <docker-image> bash
A real example:
docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu bash

You can note in the Task Manager or the top/htop/btop the performance, apparently the normal behavior for the graphics card by using the container is to grab the most quantity of VRam of your graphics card, this is scary but grabs all the memory even if we are not running the program, if you want to avoid this you can configure and tell to execution of program to use VRam only when it's necessary (program is running), I created the next code for debbuging and configure this:




import tensorflow as tf;

available_gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

print("Device listing for GPU... \n")

# Check if there is at least one GPU available supported for operating...
if len(available_gpus) == 0:
    print("GPU not recognized or not supported!")
else:
    # Show each available GPU
    for gpu in available_gpus:
        print(gpu)



Please note that if you already ran the program, and then tried to add this code, to see the effects you need to restart the jupyter notebook kernel because this code affects directly the GPU behavior.
Hardware Specifications

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x (8 cores 16 threads).
GPU: Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060 TI (8GB)

Software Specifications

Python 3.9.13 (My SO), Python 3.11 (Docker Container)
SO: Windows 11, x86_64
Docker Image: tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
tensorflow 2.16.1 (Latest Version)
tensorflowjs 4.17.0 (Latest Version)
CUDA: (According nvidia-smi) NVIDIA-SMI 552.22 Driver Version: 552.22 CUDA Version: 12.4

Why I'm not using Linux for this?
I love Linux, and I want to use it but for other reasons I can't use Linux for now, I need some Software that is only for Windows (sadly) so I'm not using it for this simple reason.
Things that I tried but didn't work

Update my graphics card drivers (nothing changes).
Use WSL 2 and tried to use tensorflow with GPU results in no recognition of my graphics card (I think this is because CUDA things that I don't have and failed to install).
Tried to install a package that apparently doesn't exists or was removed (tensorflow-gpu).
Tried to use the image tensorflow/tensorflow:2.15.0-gpu-jupyter according this post, but didn't work (when installing tensorflowjs automatically uninstall tensorflow and this breaks everything).

Partially works and progress...

Downloaded tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter image by docker desktop HUB, ran the container exposing ports 8888:8888 (results are interesting, because now the GPU is recognized and can be proved by using the command python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))" inside the container), if a tensor it's returned, then the GPU has been recognized correctly.

Steps to reproduce

If you are in Windows open Docker Desktop and search for the image tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter, download from HUB or pull manually the image.

Deploy image directly by pressing start button in containers, the container already have the configuration to run directly without problems, but if you are using a terminal and not the GUI you can run docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter bash to run image supporting GPU.

To access the Jupyter Notebook server within a browser you need to see the logs of your container and check for the link provided with the access token, something like:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=83e92bf57f929371991324ffeb50038cec0b694c6c8bc06b


Access is protected with a token so this is the reason why you need to see the log.

Run the program, the original source is this note that it's a really simple example, but this example and other cases fail with the same error when trying to export the model to a tensorflowjs model.

If you don't want to use the link of google collab above (and yes, I know in collab works, but not working in my local machine), here is also the plain code:


#Codigo general
#Si quieres ver como lo programamos, revisa el video donde lo explico
#todo desde cero: https://youtu.be/iX_on3VxZzk

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

celsius = np.array([-40, -10, 0, 8, 15, 22, 38], dtype=float)
fahrenheit = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100], dtype=float)

oculta1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, input_shape=[1])
oculta2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3)
salida = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
modelo = tf.keras.Sequential([oculta1, oculta2, salida])

modelo.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
    loss='mean_squared_error'
)

print("Comenzando entrenamiento...")
historial = modelo.fit(celsius, fahrenheit, epochs=300, verbose=False)
print("Modelo entrenado!")


resultado = modelo.predict([100.0])
print("Prediccion: 100 grados celsius son " + str(resultado) + " fahrenheit!")


#Exportar el modelo en formato h5
modelo.save('celsius_a_fahrenheit.h5')

#El equipo es Linux. Listemos el contenido de la carpeta actual para ver que se exporto el modelo
!ls
#Para convertirlo a tensorflow.js, primero debemos instalar la libreria
!pip install tensorflowjs
#Crear carpeta donde se colocaran los archivos resultantes
!mkdir carpeta_salida


#Realizar la exportacion a la carpeta de salida
# This thing here FAILS with ERROR (duplicate weight name kernel)
!tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras celsius_a_fahrenheit.h5 carpeta_salida

#Confirmar que en la carpeta de salida se hayan generado los archivos. Deben aparecer archivos "bin" y "json"
!ls carpeta_salida



Expected behavior or desired result
I only want to use the GPU version of tensorflow and be able to export a keras model to tensorflowjs in my Windows machine, I don't know if there is a solution for this error, but seems that it's a bug or incompatibilty with tensorflowjs for exporting, is there another option to export and use the tensorflow model in Web or exporting directly to tensorflowjs model?

Note: (No I don't have or defined a weight/variable/layer named kernel or things like that), if I use a (model.summary) and print the info all of them have a different name, there is no a "duplicated weight name kernel" as described in the error.
